# Change CSV file column name

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file which contains four columns i.e Name, Surname, Age, Data of Birth

I want to change the column Name to FullName. How can this be done in c# please?

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\myCSV.csv"));            

var line = reader.ReadLine();
var values = line.Split(';');

var title = line.Split(',');

Console.WriteLine(title[0]);

if (title.Contains("Name"))
{
    title[0] = "FullName";
}
```

Now I'm stuck on how should I continue to change the Column name

Comment: 1) Open the text file 2) read the first line 3) edit the string 4) write the first line 5) write the remaining lines.  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Do you want to change name in the physical file? You have to provide more information, what have you tried? Show us some code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: A CSV-file does not know any column-names, its a simple text-files filled with data of any type. You may write some strings in the first row that you won´t handle as data to give every column a meaning. Thus you may simply overwrite the very first line and that´s it...

Comment: So do you want to write a new csv file with 3 columns?

Comment: No, I just want to change "Name" to "FullName"

Comment: @Xupla So you want to change the string `Name` to `FullName` in the first row (Header) of the data which represents two columns.  If you don't do anything to combine the data, then your header doesn't match your data.  I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to acheive, look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19520898/2145211) and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are attempting to create a new file with 3 columns instead of 4 this would be a starting point, however, you should use a csv parser.  This is just a demonstration to show you how to combine the two columns.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\myCSV.csv");
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\myCSV2.csv"))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line==lines[0])
            {   //Change Header
                file.WriteLine("Fullname,Age,Date of Birth");
            }
            else
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1},{2},{3}",
                    values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3]));
            }
        }
    }
```